# Github API: Get 'body' for all new releases in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, github-api

I have a python script that fetches for updates from GitHub and displays patch-notes for the latest version when doing so.

**I would like the script to display patch-notes for all releases ahead of the current version/release.**

My github releases are versioned as so: `v1.2.3`

This is the code I am currently using that displays patch notes for the latest release only:

```
version = 2.1.5

import urllib.request, json

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.github.com/repos/:author/:repo/releases/latest") as url:
  data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
  latest = data['tag_name'][1:] # "v2.3.6" -> "2.3.6"
  patchNotes = data['body']

if latest > version:
    print('\nUpdate available!')
    print(f'Latest Version: v{latest}')
    print('\n'+str(patchNotes)+'\n') #display latest (v2.3.6) patch notes
    input(str('Update now? [Y/n] ')).upper()
    #code to download the latest version
```

This is an idea I have had to get what I need:

1. Get all release version numbers (e.g 1.2.3)
2. Add all version numbers that are ahead of the current into an array
3. For version in array, get `data[body]` from respective github-api json page
4. Print the patch-notes in the correct order (oldest (one version ahead of current) to newest (latest version)

I don't know how to impliment the above idea, and if there are more efficient ways of achieving what I'm going for, I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
import requests
from packaging import version

maxVersion = version.parse("3.9.2")
repoWithOwner= "labstack/echo"

r = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/{}/releases?per_page=100".format(repoWithOwner))
releases = [ 
    (t["tag_name"],t["body"]) 
    for t in r.json() 
    if version.parse(t["tag_name"]) >= maxVersion
][::-1]

for r in releases:
    print("{} : {}".format(r[0],r[1]))
```

It gets the 100 last releases & check wether it is >= {your specified version}, reverse the array and print the tag & body

Comment: What significance do variables **r** and **t** have (what do they contain/mean) and what are they used for?

Comment: @OverflowingStack r is the result of requests, t is the variable in the [comprehension list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@Bertrand Martel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58477757/9457576), edited for my needs

I used Python 3's pre-installed libraries **urllib.request** and **json** (so that it's more portable), and `f-strings` instead of `.format`

```
import urllib.request, json

ver='3.0.0' #Current scripts version
author='labstack'
repo='echo'

release = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(f'https://api.github.com/repos/{author}/{repo}/releases?per_page=5').read().decode())
releases = [
    (data['tag_name'],data['body'])
    for data in release
    if data['tag_name'] > ver][::-1]
for release in releases:
    print(f'{release[0]}:\n{release[1]}\n')
```